# What is the difference between setAdapter and setListAdapter in android?

Tags: android

I just want to know where to use setAdapter and setListadapter.
I searched it out but haven't finding anything suitable.

Answer (score 2):

`setListAdapter` is a method of `ListActivity`. It just sets the adapter for the `ListView` that the activity manages. `setAdapter` is a method of `ListView` (and of other classes as well). You only call `setListAdapter` when talking to a `ListActivity` object; otherwise you call `setAdapter`.